# How to replicate large well powered mixed effects model with a smaller sample?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, statistical-power

Some edits made...

I have a dataset which other researchers have used mixed effects modelling with to come up with a nice set of associations. I also have a much smaller dataset which is the same variables but from a different country. The first dataset is plenty powerful enough (350 individuals from 30 locations) but the second dataset is not very powerful at all (70 individuals from 15 locations).

Is there some way to take what I know about the first data set and use it to boost the power of the second dataset? I've pooled all the data and analysed it and replicated the results, but I fear that is because the first dataset is just swamping the second one. So far I've come up with:

1) Analyse first dataset, then pool, analyse again, and compare AIC to see if it gets worse (seems a bit crude).

2) Analyse both datasets using a dummy variable for first/ second dataset (they're from different countries). This seems like a good idea but I'm not convinced it would eliminate the whole problem of the first swamping the second.

3) It sounds a bit like Bayesian statistics, but I don't know the first thing about Bayesian statistics, so if it is this then I'd better hit the library.

Any and all help as ever gratefully received!

Clarifications:

1) dependent variable same for both countries
2) oh dear, not sure I understand this question. All the variables are the same, so I have a list of their data, with a country code, and then the same variables again, with a different country code. All observations are individuals clustered in wards clustered in countries. Does this answer?
3) Really I'm just trying to replicate the significant linear associations which they found (or, I guess, highlight where they are different). So e.g. they found that size of ward improved outcomes, we would like to replicate that, along with some other associations.

Comment: Some points to clarify: 1. Is your dependent variable the same for both countries?  2. How did you pool both country data? 3. What type of the conclusions you are trying to make? My general observation is that if you pool both countries, you must assume that the same association applies in both of them. This usually is quite strong assumption. If it holds, then simply adding country specific variables to your pooled analysis might be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a hierarchical model: you would have a country-level effect, and nested within that would be a location-level effect. I've only ever skimmed through it, but the Gelman and Hill book seems to be quite highly regarded in this area:
http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/

As for whether this sounds Bayesian: this is one area where the distinction between Bayesian and non-Bayesian techniques becomes very blurred. Personally, I find it easier to think of these models in Bayesian terms, because then you don't need to get bogged down in making the distinction between fixed and random effects.